# GitHub - failed to create remote repository

Tags: github, terminal

I have a repository- 'repo1' in our company's GitHub cloud.

`git remote -v`, shows -

```
origin  git@github.****:***/repo1.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.****:***/repo1.git (push)
```

Now I am trying to add a new remote repo - 'repo2' with the command line:

```
projectName=repo2
mkdir $projectName
cd $projectName
git init -b $projectName
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
git remote add origin ****:***/repo2.git
git push -u origin $projectName
```

and I get an error in the last command:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It is worth emphasizing that the repo was created with local success.
also, `git remote -v`, shows

```
origin  git@github.****:***/repo2.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.****:***/repo2.git (push)
```

but failed to push to remote.

also is worth emphasizing, that I could add a new repo in our GitHub site. The only problem occurs when adding from the terminal.

Comment: "Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists." -- did you consider this information? I mean, just pushing doesn't implicitly create a repository on the remote side. Even if it could, it might require certain permissions.

Comment: I could add a new repo in our GitHub site.
The only problem occurs when adding from terminal.
I will add this comment to the question.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71773308/10951191) on GitHub forums, that the new repo must be created on GitHub site before doing the `git push`